# How do I convert an roc object to a grob? I have multiclass roc graphs that need to be in one panel and have tried par, grid.arrange, ggpubr, etc

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, par

I've tried using par, plot, cowplot, grid.arrange, ggpubr and none of these work. Additionally, the legend doesn't appear or is too big.

```
library(ggplot2)

p1<-plot(rocmenv, col = 1, lty = 2)#black dashed
plot(rocmenvnb, col = 2, lty = 3, add = TRUE)#red dotted
plot(rocmenvnn, col=3, lty=4, add=TRUE)#green dotdash
plot(rocmenvdt, col=4, lty=5, add=TRUE)# blue longdash

## Add Legend
legend("bottomright",
   legend = c("Random Forest: AUC 92%", "Naive Bayes: AUC 97%", "Neural Network:AUC       100%", "Decision Tree:AUC 64%"), 
   col = c("black", "red", "green", "blue"),
   lty = c(2, 3, 4, 5), xpd = TRUE, cex = 0.6)#black dashed

p2<-plot(rocbombv, col = 1, lty = 2)#black dashed
plot(rocbombvnb, col = 2, lty = 3, add = TRUE)#red dotted
plot(rocbombvnn, col=3, lty=4, add=TRUE)#green dotdash
plot(rocbombvdt, col=4, lty=5, add=TRUE)# blue longdash

## Add Legend
legend("bottom", 
   legend = c("Random Forest: AUC 88%", "Naive Bayes: AUC 93%", "Neural Network:AUC 100%", "Decision Tree:AUC 75%"), 
   col = c("black", "red", "green", "blue"),
   lty = c(2, 3, 4, 5), xpd = TRUE)
```

Comment: We don't have rocmenv, and don't know what class it is (there are many classes in R extension packages for representing roc curves). Since `plot` is generic, the type of the resulting plot is unknowable to us, and therefore your question is literally unanswerable unless you share the data with us using `dput`, or at the very least, tell us which package you are using and explain something about how your data is structured.

Comment: I agree with Alans comment. Please share the dput of your data so we can help.